# asp.net Invalid character in a Base-64 string

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, viewstate, base64

I have a c# mobile site and have a problem with some of mobile clients. I have posted a trace below but basically browser of phone or wap gateway that phone connects to internet url encodes viewstate hidden input in the form.

> /wEPDwULLTExNTMyOTcwOTBkGAEFBlBtTGlzdA9nZA==

becomes

> %2FwEPDwULLTExNTMyOTcwOTBkGAEFBlBtTGlzdA9nZA%3D%3D

so viewstate fails.

Is there anyway to override and urldecode viewstate info before proccessing?

```
System.Web.HttpException: The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted. ---> System.Web.UI.ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. 
 Client IP: 65.91.116.34
 Port: 37172
 User-Agent: SCH-R430 UP.Browser/6.2.3.8 (GUI) MMP/2.0
 ViewState: %2FwEPDwULLTExNTMyOTcwOTBkGAEFBlBtTGlzdA9nZA%3D%3D
 Referer: 
 Path: /mobile/Inbox.aspx ---> System.FormatException: Invalid character in a Base-64 string.
   at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
   at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString)
   at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Deserialize(String serializedState)
   at System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, String serializedState)
   at System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError)
   at System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowViewStateError(Exception inner, String persistedState)
   at System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.mobile_inbox_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: (deleted my answer as I didn't spot the "viewstate" bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement a custom ViewStatePersister object which handles this. You probably want to derive it from [HiddenFieldPageStatePersister](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.hiddenfieldpagestatepersister.aspx).  Take a look at [this article](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/mamanzes_blog/archive/2006/08/27/Save-some-space_2C00_-compress-that-ViewState.aspx) which shows how to implement compression on top of ViewState, but is very similar to what you need to do.

There's a little bit of hackiness involved: you'll need to use reflection to set a field of the [StateFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pagestatepersister.stateformatter.aspx) base class which is, contrary to what the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pagestatepersister.stateformatter.aspx) say, not marked as virtual so can't be overridden without reflection.

Answer (score -1):

Use below solution and check if it works. It works for me. Add this code in   your asp.net code behind which is causing the issue. Below code is in vb.net

```
Protected Overrides Function LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() As Object
        Return Session("_ViewState")
    End Function
Protected Overrides Sub SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(viewState As Object)
        Session("_ViewState") = viewState
    End Sub
```

Comment: You need to provide code in the programming language the question asks, *not* the programming language of your choice.