# Invalid character in a Base-64 string. ASP .NET with Jmeter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, base64, jmeter

I am trying to record Jmeter scripts against some ASP .NET application. (this application is owned by some xyz company) . The app works fine when I run it without Jmeter. 
As soon as I start Jmeter proxy and start recording the app dies on second page ...

Here is the exception I see on the browser. Also its https enabled so made sure the certs are present in proxyserver.jks under apache bin directory.

**Invalid character in a Base-64 string.**

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details: System.FormatException: Invalid character in a Base-64 string.**

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

> [FormatException: Invalid character in a Base-64 string.]
>   System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s) +0
>   FirstAppBusinessLogic.DynamicPages.UrlEncryption.Decrypt(String
>   inputText) +57    QueryStringHttpModule.context_BeginRequest(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +246
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +68    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

I see a similar post here 
[ASP.NET Invalid character in a Base-64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810232/asp-net-invalid-character-in-a-base-64-string)

But in my case it happens only when I try to record using Jmeter. Normally with out Jmeter proxy everything seems fine.

Any help ?

-Ram

Comment: Off-topic: I wouldn't have called a class dealing with base64 `UrlEncryption`. The *`Encryption`* part of the name is kinda bothering me. Besides this, there's too little context in your question to diagnose this problem.

Comment: Hi Darin,
Thanks for your comment. This code is written by some third party. All I am trying to do is access there URL (Web app)  and want to make sure there web app can serve the load. So I was trying to record Jmeter scripts for this app to do some load testing.

Comment: This also has absolutely nothing to do with [tag:asp-classic]. I don't know how many times I have to say this! Please [learn the difference](http://www.dotnetspider.com/tutorials/AspNet-Tutorial-26.aspx).

Comment: Paul,
My question is related to the app not working when I use Jmeter proxy. So how is this related to your comment saying "I don't know how many times I have to say this! Please learn the difference between Classic ASP vs ASP .NET". I feel your comment is out of context. Sorry.

Comment: What requests is jmeter making and how are they encoded? Jmeter will only encode if you tell it to.

Comment: Hi Charlie,
      
That's true. My only concern is this .net webapp has https url . If I inspect the cert,its a self signed cert. So the rootcert is not one of the standard certs like (thwarte, versign..etc).  I beleive that shouldn't be an issue. so I enabled https recording as mentioned here https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterAndHTTPS
I am using Jmeter version 2.11 which supports https recording.

However the app works fine when I dont use Jmeter. This app is owned by some third party. so there argument is it works fine normally. So Jmeter may not be sending correct requests.

Answer (score 0):

Thank your for all your inputs. After troubleshooting further I noticed that there was query parameter in url with value "==".

Since "==" is not one of the value you can send unless its urlencoded this was breaking the flow. Asked the other team to urlencode all query params and the issue was resolved.